# It's not ___, but it's not not ___ either

Tags: negation, litotes

Are there general modifiers for adjectives that indicate a gray area between the adjective and its negative?

E.g., "Plywood isn't wooden, but it isn't not-wooden either. Therefore, plywood is ____ly wooden." What goes in the blank?

"Partially" doesn't sound quite right, because it suggests that one piece of the noun really *is* described by the adjective; I'm looking for a word that places the whole noun in the middle of an adjective-spectrum.

Sorry for the dumb example, but that's just off the top of my head. Better examples would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Plywood is *sort of* wooden.

Comment: There but not quite there.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I really didn't expect there to be a one-size word for this, but thought I'd throw it out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> "Therefore, plywood is *quasi-wooden*".
>
> "Therefore, plywood is *pseudo-wooden*".
>
> "Therefore, plywood is *semi-wooden*".
>
> "Therefore, plywood is *only nominally wooden*".

Comment: Yes; these answers address the 'non-X, or at least not completely X, but not unconnected with X' notion I hope is behind the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Plywood is somewhat wooden
>
> Plywood is sort of wooden
>
> Plywood is kind of wooden
>
> Plywood is more or less wooden

etc...

> **somewhat (adv.)**
>
> 1) matters have improved somewhat: a little, a bit, to some extent,
>   (up) to a point, in some measure, rather, quite, some; *informal:* kind
>   of, kinda, sort of, sorta. ANTONYMS greatly.
>
> 2) a somewhat thicker
>   book: slightly, relatively, comparatively, moderately, fairly, rather,
>   quite, marginally.

*Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus*

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's perfectly accurate to say "plywood is wooden." I know it contains other materials, and since it does, it would be inaccurate to say, "plywood is wood."

Basically, I think you're fine saying "plywood is wooden" though it's not only made of wood.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head: by definition, something can't be both X and non-X. And using different polysemes ( It's coffee, but it's not _coffee_ coffee) has to be done with great care. Collins definitions essentially imply that plywood is both wooden and not wooden: **wooden** 1. (Forestry) made from or consisting of wood. 'Plywood is a wood-based semi-synthetic board material containing other essential materials.'

Comment: By definition -- yes, but I'm not really looking for a modifier to pin down an "accurate" description as much as one with that definition-evading frustration built in. I suppose that it would be most useful when modifying a more subjective adjective -- perhaps a personality type.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use "[somewhat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/somewhat):" in some degree or measure.

Some examples that come to mind:

That video game is *somewhat* popular; it is not unpopular, but it is not popular.

He uses *somewhat* proper grammar; it is not proper (perhaps he misuses semi-colons occassionally), but it is not what most people would call improper.

Note, though, that *somewhat* only weakens the adjective, so it's not a truly gray area.